# version 10.6.6 when the installed package is version 3.2.6

Tags: php, rocky-linux, rhel9

I've built php 8.1 from source. one php app uses mysqli extension
I get this warning:

HP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:100606 Library:30206 in /home/www/www/mitest.php on line 17

Where 3.2.6 is version of mariadb connector, 10.6.6 is version of mariadb. well not the installed mariadb, but the one that connector comes from? I don't know it's wierd. Installed mariadb version is 10.5.22. **All versions are from the OS repo, up to date. I did a make clean and configure + make after update to be sure.**

```
# yum list mariadb-connector-c-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 1:07:13 ago on Sun 24 Mar 2024 11:59:26 PM EET.
Installed Packages
mariadb-connector-c-devel.aarch64            3.2.6-1.el9_0            @appstream
# /usr/bin/mariadb_config --version
10.6.6
```

mariadb_config comes from the connector package:

```
yum provides /usr/bin/mariadb_config
Last metadata expiration check: 1:17:29 ago on Sun 24 Mar 2024 11:59:26 PM EET.
mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.2.6-1.el9_0.aarch64 : Development files for
                                                : mariadb-connector-c
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/mariadb_config

mariadb-connector-c-devel-3.2.6-1.el9_0.aarch64 : Development files for
                                                : mariadb-connector-c
Repo        : appstream
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/mariadb_config
```

from php -i:

mysqli

```
MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => 3.2.6
Active Persistent Links => 0
Inactive Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API header version => 10.6.6-MariaDB
MYSQLI_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Is this a bug in mysqli extension or am I doing something wrong

Comment: It's a different client, the version numbers don't have to match. Furthermore, the `-devel` packages only contain header files you need for development using this library, it is usually not needed in a production environment.